# Analyzing a Gatsby Bundle File for Slow Load

Tags: reactjs, webpack, gatsby

I have a large SPA which takes a second or two to load completely. What can I use to figure out what is causing my SPA to have a slow first load?
[This](https://video.twimg.com/tweet_video/ES7ETvkVAAAj3H6.mp4) is a video of the issue.

I have removed all calls to APIs. I've tried tools such as `gatsby-plugin-webpack-bundle-analyser-v2`, but I don't believe it's accurate. On `gatsby build`, it shows a bundle size of 10mb where the actual bundle `.js` file is only 2.3mb.

I can't figure out how to export a webpack-stats file to use `https://chrisbateman.github.io/webpack-visualizer/`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export a stat file with `gatsby-plugin-webpack-bundle-analyser-v2`, you need to pass this option :

*gatsby-config.js*

```js
{
    resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-webpack-bundle-analyser-v2',
    options: {
        generateStatsFile: true,
    },
},
```

It will generate JSON file named `stats.json` in your `/public` dir.

Hope this helps.